# Trouble calling js method from Flash AS2

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

First of all, I'm a complete noob in Flash and don't really know what I'm doing :/ (it's a favour for a friend)

So I've seen many people suggesting using

```
getURL("javascript:myFunction();");
```

for calling the method myFunction that I have in my html file (in the head).
However, for some reason the method is not invoked.
The code I have in my frame that tries to invoke the method is

```
getURL("javascript:myFunction();");
stop();
```

And it simply stops a flash film that ends. 
I do also have on my html under the  :

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

and again in the nested `<!--[if !IE]>-->` .

(If needs be, I can add the html file as well.)
Can anyone shed a light on what am I doing wrong? Removing the stop(); doesn't seem to change anything either (apart of the film being replayed.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this, call js funciton using ExternalInterface.

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("myFunction()");
```

As I checked `getURL("javascript:myFunction();");` should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems like this is not working for me whether I put it before or after the stop(); :/

Comment: This is not working for AS2 but for AS3. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13642847/174929