# Unable to invoke javascript from flash AS2

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

First of all, I'm a complete noob in Flash and don't really know what I'm doing :/ (it's a favour for a friend).

I'm working with CS6 and using action script 2.

So I've seen many people suggesting using

```
getURL("javascript:myFunction();");
```

or

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.call("myFunction()");
```

for calling the method myFunction that I have in my html file (in the head). However, for some reason the method is not invoked. Apart of that I have in my frame code that just stops a flash film that ends (I tried putting this before and after the js invocation)

```
stop();
```

I do also have on my html under the `<object>`:

```
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
```

and again in the nested `<!--[if !IE]>-->` .

(If needs be, I can add the html file as well.) Can anyone shed a light on what am I doing wrong? Removing the stop(); doesn't seem to change anything either (apart of the film being replayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is a rather silly thing, but I've decided to put it down in writing in case someone in the future will stumble upon the same weird behaviour.
What happened was I have installed Flash CS6 on the same day and didn't reboot my machine. After rebooting it, calling `getURL("javascript:myFunction();");` simply worked- just remember to also have the `<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />` on your html.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the first method, but have for the second. Try it without the brackets:

```
ExternalInterface.call("myFunction");
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but it looks like this is not working at all for AS2; anyway the issue was a whole different thing- see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
flash.external.ExternalInterface.call("function (without brackets)","Value or Variable(Without quotes)");
```